# BaseAdapter android getCount() method

Tags: android, arraylist, baseadapter

I am trying to setup a BaseAdapter for a ListView but i have an error at run time. The error is in NewsAdapter.java file in getCount method: if i write "return 0" i have no error but if write "return list.size()" i have  the error at run time.
Here is all the file: 
**News.java**

```
public class News extends Activity {

TextView txt1;
ArrayList<NewsArray> listaArray;
NewsAdapter baseAdapter;
ListView lista;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

    txt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    lista= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    baseAdapter= new NewsAdapter(this, R.layout.newsframe, listaArray);
    lista.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.news, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
```

**NewsAdapter.java**

```
public class NewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<NewsArray> list=new ArrayList<NewsArray>();
Context c;
int layoutResourceId;

public NewsAdapter(Context c, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<NewsArray> list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.c = c;
    this.list = list;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
    //return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(arg0);

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;

}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;
}
}
```

**NewsArray.java**

```
public class NewsArray  {
String  name, nickname, date, description, ncomment, nlike;

public NewsArray(String name, String nickname, String date, String description, String ncoment, String nlike) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.name=name;
    this.nickname=nickname;
    this.date=date;
    this.description=description;
    this.ncomment=ncoment;
    this.nlike=nlike;
}
}
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the constructor of the `ArrayList<NewsArray> listaArray` before create the adapter:

```
listaArray = new ArrayList<NewsArray>();
```

This is because if you pass an `ArrayList` as an argument you are passing just a reference. You should copy the content on your BaseAdapter constructor:

```
this.list = new ArrayList<NewsArray>(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return statement of `getView`. You could also try an `ArrayAdapter` instead of reinventing the wheel, unless you need to.

Also DavidGSola says in his answer, you are not initializing your ArrayList correctly.